# Self-hosted cloud storage with global selective sync

Tags: windows, linux, self-hosted, cloud-storage

I would like to put in place a self-hosted cloud storage solution (on Linux), which would allow for a **global** selective sync.

As an example, I would like that a directory called `hello`  and `*.jpg` files are never synchronized, no matter the place.

I do not care about any other feature, the only hard requirements are:

- global selective sync
- server based on Linux
- clients for Linux and Windows

The only solution which I found doing this is Mega.nz, but it is commercially hosted.

Answer (score 1):

i would definitely recommend [**Nextcloud**](https://nextcloud.com/), although i'm not 100% sure that i understand what your goal is...

- first it is FOSS and therefor **self-hosting (for sure on linux)** is no problem.
- dedicated FOSS-**clients** are available for **linux, windows**, mac, android, ios and even windows mobile. but also on other platforms, or if you don't like them, it shouldn't be a problem since file-exchange is done via WebDAV; so every WebDAV-client is fine.
- a bunch of apps (expandable functions, like contacts, calender, tasks, mails, newsreader,...) do also integrate into resp. interact/synchronize with other applications flawlessly, since standard-protocols & -formats are used.

now regarding your special recommendation (***global selective sync***)...

- either you **use the client** and deselect the unwanted folder and/or add the extension which should be ignored to the list in the settings. - i guess this isn't what you are looking for... but the other answer was about this; maybe this confused me a little bit.
- or if you are the admin of the instance and don't want such a file/folder on your server at all, you should have a look at the [***Ransomware protection*** app](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/ransomware_protection). it is designed in first place for something other - as the name says - but i guess with this you can accomplish your goals.
- if not, maybe take a look at the [**config.php**](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#all-other-configuration-options)'s line `'blacklisted_files' => array('.htaccess'),`, but only use/change it, if you really know what are you doing!

and the last advice i want to express is, if you are fine with the folder/files on your server, but want to restrict access (not just for some users, but for other special conditions) [*File access control*](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/files_accesscontrol) is the app you should look at a bit closer.
i mention this, because hopefully you are aware of, that blocking before uploading just checks/works with the name of the files/folders (renaming and uploading will still be possible - or also the same pictures with a `.jpeg`-extension may exist...), but a check of the files on the server also works with mime-types for example.
--> maybe both checks/apps in combination will make sense to be on the safe side...

Answer (score 0):

below service may compatible for your needs

1. https://owncloud.org
2. https://nextcloud.com

and comment if you need more help

Comment: Thanks. I used to run owncloud and nextcloud but did not find the global ignore setting. Where is it? As for Tonido, it depends on an external service (it is self-hosted but access is done though their cloud)

Comment: https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=20292
does-it-solve your problem?
however have other products but so far at security risk so i dont prefer recommend
here's some selfhost various service may useful for you
https://github.com/Kickball/awesome-selfhosted

Comment: owncloud/nextcloud you can isolate them
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/docker/
and
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-nextcloud-integrated-with-onlyoffice-using-docker

Comment: Tonido has sadly closed their doors, in 2022.